# Unit testing in Django

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-testing

Let's suppose I do some change to a function in the `tests.py` file, like monkey patching the `clean` method of some form...

**When all the tests are finished, will that method still have associated the function I assigned?**

A concrete example (to avoid captcha validation when testing):

```
from myapp.fields import ReCaptchaField
ReCaptchaField.clean = lambda x, y: y[0]
```

The same applies to adding/changing some field in the `settings.py` file...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will remain associated. That's the benefit/side-effect/danger of monkey-patching, change the default behavior during the process lifetime.